# calling a CL program from RPGLE program issues

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, cl

I'm trying to call a CL programm from an RPGLE.
I didn't do this before. I've always done the oposit ( callin an rpgle from a CL)
Is it possible ? through a callp or a QCMDEXC ???

Answer (score 3):

You can call any program from RPGLE like you call QCMDEXC, you have to define a prototype with extpgm keyword and use it like a procedure

```
dcl-pr name_inside_rpgle extpgm('*LIBL/CLPGMNAME'); // program name MUST be uppercased 
  ...
end-pr;

name_inside_rpgle(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

`CALLP` and `QCMDEXEC` do two very different things. `CALLP` is for executing program objects (*PGM) and ILE sub-procedures (no object type, but contained in *SRVPGM or even *PGM) regardless of which language was used to compile that *PGM (or *SRVPGM) object. `QCMDEXEC` is for executing command objects (*CMD).

Let's look at the *PGM object. This is a compiled object created by one of the RPG, COBOL, C/C++, CL, PL/1 or MI compilers/assembler. All program objects can be called by any of these languages as long as the call is defined properly. For RPGLE, you can use CALL or CALLP, though CALLP is preferred because it enforces parameter type checking.

Looking at sub-procedures, these are contained in ILE program and service program (*PGM & *SRVPGM) objects. These can be created using one of the RPG, COBOL, CL, or C/C++ ILE compilers, and can be called from any ILE program regardless of the language it was created with. In fact, a single service program can contain sub-procedures from multiple languages. Sub-procedures are called in RPGLE using CALLB or CALLP, though CALLP is preferred because, as in calling program objects, it enforces parameter type checking. One caveat here, if a sub-procedure resides in a program object (*PGM) it can only be called from within that program object. Shared sub-procedures must be compiled into service programs. There is a type of sharing where sub-procedure source is shared, and the modules are then linked directly into the program object. I don't really consider this shared code since only the source is shared, the executable is not.

That brings us to command objects (*CMD) These are special objects created by CRTCMD. Commands can be executed on the command line by just typing the command name like `WRKACTJOB`. They may have parameters, or not. These are the things executed by `QCMDEXEC`, which, by the way, is a program object, so is callable using `CALLP` in an RPGLE program.

Comment: This is a great comparison of these different executable units and how they can be called.

Answer (score 0):

some notes I have from 16 years ago...best of luck.

```
/IF Defined(*CRTBNDRPG)
H DFTACTGRP(*NO)
/ENDIF
H BNDDIR('QC2LE')
D GoCmd PR 10I 0 Extproc('system')
D CmdStr * value
D options(*string)
D NullString C -1
D Success C 0
D Returncode S 10I 0
D User S 10 Inz(*User) Varying
/free
   Returncode = Gocmd('DLYJOB DLY(300)');  //change to another CL command here
   Select;
   When Returncode = Success; // Command was successful
   When Returncode = NullString; // Command string was null
   Other;
   Endsl;
   *INLR=*ON;
/end-free
```